# sass is watching only once on ubuntu?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, watch

I installed sass on Ubuntu. Then I wrote sass --watch scss:css then It worked only once. Now, I am using it but for every code I must write sass --watch scss:css. I mean it works only once. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, please explain your folder structure as well. Is your scss and css existing folders? Does scss contain .sass or .scss files? I googled quickly and read the documentation on https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass and found out that you need to specify a folder of .sass or .scss files to watch multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run one command in package.json file to watch continuously.

Update "scripts" package.json file as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-css": "node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss   public/css/main.css",
    "watch-css": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run build-css\""
},
```

Here, in build-css, set path of scss and css file.
And run the below command in cmd

```
npm run watch-css
```

You are ready to go.
You can also refer below link for more details:

https://medium.com/@brianhan/watch-compile-your-sass-with-npm-9ba2b878415b